# Tests failing intermittently with shardTestFiles set to true

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

My tests are passing reliably without shardTestFiles, but with shardTestFiles true I am getting intermittent  in different places.  The error message is the following:

Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "Cannot read property '$$testability' of undefined"

This is from my config file:

```js
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs            : ['tests/e2e/**/*.js'],
  rootElement: 'body#rootElement',

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances:11
  },

  allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 500000,
    isVerbose: true
  }
};
```

How do I get my reliable tests to run reliably with shardTestFiles on?

Comment: Just add `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` in your test case

Comment: I turn off synchronization for my non-Angular login page, but turn in on for all my other pages.  It is so much nicer to write tests with it on and they run reliably without sharding.

Comment: So it worked for you?

Comment: All my tests would fail if I turned off synchronization.  They were written using the built in flow control.